# How to enable bluetooth in beaglebone black

Tags: linux, root-filesystem, beagleboneblack

I bringup beaglebone black successfully with my own rootfs.

After bringup beaglebone black how to enable peripherals like gpio,bluetooth and wifi from scratch

please suggest me

Comment: Can you add more information about the system you installed to the beaglebone?

Comment: i got this error after bringup 0.000000] ** IfStarting network: ifup: can't open '/var/run/ifstate.new': No such file or directory
FAIL
May 18 11:56:26 buildroot daemon.info : starting pid 278, tty '/dev/console': '/sbin/getty -L  console 0 vt100 '

Welcome to Buildroot
buildroot login:

Comment: It's hard to say, but you might not have a fully functional system in the Beaglebone. You might want to also consider [installing a full pre-configured image](https://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Method_1:_Download_a_Complete_Pre-Configured_Image) and then customizing it.