# ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, ifconfig

Running `ifconfig wlan0 up` returns

```
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
```

I tried `ifconfig wlan0` and got

```
ifconfig: wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

Boot-up logs showing

```
Starting network: [    6.178148] ip (252) used greatest stack depth: 5756 bytes left
/bin/sh: wpa_supplicant: not found
FAIL
```

How can I debug this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should start by reading your distribution's documentation about how to configure networking. Since the tools, package names and files might differ between them. Of course telling here what distribution is used might have helped (at least to be pointed to the doc).

Comment: Also previous comment about installing a known-to-be-working distribution on Beagle Black still stands: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595053/how-to-enable-bluetooth-in-beaglebone-black#comment1110492_595053 , or https://beagleboard.org/getting-started , https://beagleboard.org/latest-images . Of course wireless requires a [BeagleBone Black *Wireless*](https://beagleboard.org/black-wireless), not the ethernet variant.

Comment: Hi,I have taken android kernal(3.18) android uboot,and minimal rootfs (buildroot and busybox) after this I successfully bring up my board .after added wlan0 configuration in interfaces file then I running ifconfig wlan0 up it showing above errors distribution is debian

Comment: distribution is Debian using a buildroot created rootfs and an Android kernel 3.18 which is EOL? Somewhere I have doubts.